# My simple sqoop export failed on map phase in the job

Tags: sqoop

I am learning sqoop export and here is my command:

```
sqoop export -m 1 \
--connect jdbc:mysql://ms.itversity.com:3306/retail_export \
--username=<username> \
--password=<password> \
--table dep_export \
--export-dir departments_new \
--input-lines-terminated-by '\n' \
--input-fields-terminated-by '|'
```

This command means to export the data on hdfs to mysql but it failed for the following details:

> Error: java.io.IOException: Can't export data, please check failed map
>   task logs at
>   org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.TextExportMapper.map(TextExportMapper.java:122)
>   at
>   org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.TextExportMapper.map(TextExportMapper.java:39)
>   at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:146) at
>   org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.AutoProgressMapper.run(AutoProgressMapper.java:64)
>   at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:787) at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341) at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:168) at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at
>   javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422) at
>   org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1724)
>   at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:162) Caused
>   by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't parse input data:
>   '10,physicss,2018-01-31 22:24:18.0' at
>   dep_export.__loadFromFields(dep_export.java:316) at
>   dep_export.parse(dep_export.java:254) at
>   org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.TextExportMapper.map(TextExportMapper.java:89)
>   ... 10 more Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input
>   string: "10,physicss,2018-01-31 22:24:18.0" at
>   java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
>   at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580) at
>   java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Integer.java:766) at
>   dep_export.__loadFromFields(dep_export.java:303) ... 12 more

Can someone help to sort it out? Thank you very much.

Comment: Please paste the yarn logs for more details on the error l. If you go to the yarn logs failed mappers it will show the exact error.

Comment: Thank you, I still do not have the log but from Job History Server it really shows no useful error detail there:Diagnostics: 
Task failed task_1517228278761_16138_m_000000
Job failed as tasks failed. failedMaps:1 failedReduces:0
Link posted here although not sure if you can see the log directly: http://rm01.itversity.com:19888/jobhistory/job/job_1517228278761_16138

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your data is ',' delimited , try using the below

> --input-fields-terminated-by ','